# If petit biscuit means "cookie," then do you say petit twice to say "small cookie"?

Tags: expressions

If petit biscuit means "cookie," then do you say petit twice to say "small cookie", like "Je mange un petit petit biscuit"?

Comment: Where did you get that? A cookie is *biscuit* not *petit biscuit*. *Biscuit* in French is "biscuit" in Br. English (cookie in Am. English) as [a dictionary could have told you](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/biscuit). A small cookie is *un petit biscuit*.

Comment: Besides, a cookie can be a "biscuit", but all "biscuits" are not cookies.

Comment: You could check your source and see if what you heard for "cookie" was not *petit biscuit* but *petit gâteau sec* which some people used to say for a *biscuit* a long time ago (over 50-60 years, I haven't heard it since my childhood).

Answer (score 1):

S'il est vraiment petit, vous pouvez dire "un tout petit biscuit" pour insister sur votre frugalité ;) mais ne doublez pas petit.